# Как сделать запрос в django из одной модели в другую?

Tags: python, django

Есть три класса в models - Movies -  Country -  Cities

Movies связанна с Countries

```
class Movies (models.Model):
country = models.ManyToManyField('Country', blank=True, null=True)
```

Cities связанна с Country

```
class Cities (models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Дальше во Views я делаю запрос, пытаясь получить все Movies в которых упоминается Cities, через Country. В документации пишут, что промежуточные запросы не нужны.

```
def get_city(request, city_slug):
    city = Cities.objects.get(slug=city_slug)
    movies = Movies.objects.filter(cities__city__contains=city.id)
    return (request, "movies/city.html", {"movies": movies,"city": city})
```

Но получаю ошибку на сайте

FieldError at /en/movies/city/new-york/
Related Field got invalid lookup: contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, ошибка связана с неправильным использованием `lookup`-запроса. В данном случае Вы пытаетесь использовать `contains` как `lookup` для поля `cities`, но `contains` не является поддерживаемым запросом для `ManyToManyField`.

В Вашем случае, Вы можете использовать `__country` для доступа к полю `Country` связанной модели `Movies`, и использовать поддерживаемые lookup-запросы для поля `Country`.

Исправленный код:

```
def get_city(request, city_slug):
    city = Cities.objects.get(slug=city_slug)
    movies = Movies.objects.filter(country__cities=city)
    return (request, "movies/city.html", {"movies": movies,"city": city})
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!